# How do English speakers say they want the same item?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, contemporary-english

Let's say a Mars bar. In my language, if one showed candy bar and we'd want one, not a part broken off, we'd say 'does it have twin?'

Comment: "Do you have another?"

Comment: "I'd like one of those".

Comment: I want one too. Polite: I'd like one also, please.

Comment: Did you bring enough for everyone? :)

Comment: I'll have the same please

Answer (score 1):

There's many examples, one of which is similar to yours.

When meeting someone's spouse or companion, a common expression to express approval is "Does he/she have a brother/sister?"

But, for common everyday things that can't be shared, you would ask "Are there more of those?" or "Do you have a spare I could use?".  In a restaurant, when one sees a diner enjoying a meal or a friend ordering something desirable, one might say "I'll have what he's having" or "Make that two."

All of these imply that the item in question is (or may not be) unique, and another can be procured.